# Expiration handler never called for beginBackgroundTask(withName:expirationHandler:)

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, background-task

I'm trying to run some final processing before the iOS application (iOS 13.1) is put into the background and was playing around with a very basic example just to see what was going on:

```
let identifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "mywork", expirationHandler: {
  print("Expiration handler called")
})

for i in 1...500 {
  print("[\(Date())] Step \(i)")
  sleep(1)
}

UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(identifier)
```

When I run the code, I then hit the home button to but app in background and then the console prints up to 55 and stops. For more context, I'm running on an actual device.

1. Why isn't the expiration handler print statement showing up? Shouldn't expiration handler be called?
2. People have been saying they usually get around 3 minutes but I'm getting less than 1 minute, is there any reason this is shorter?
3. The AppDelegate method to `applicationDidEnterBackground` isn't called either in my testing, shouldn't this method be called at the very least?
4. Is there any reason this would be shorter with file processing, because I'm trying to write some files but I seem to only get about 15 seconds of processing before it stops.

Any advice or insights would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to begin the background task when your app is already in the background, so in `didEnterBackground` or in the handler of a did enter background notification

Comment: Have you enabled the background capability in your project settings? it won't work otherwise.When you don't use this api to extend app termination then by default iOS gives you 5 seconds to finish any crucial task.

Comment: @AnshulSharma yes I've added the capability.

Comment: @Paulw11 the documentation specifies to call before entering background "Call this method as early as possible before starting your task, and preferably before your app actually enters the background."

Comment: You should also dispatch your loop onto another queue. Don't `sleep` on the main queue.

Comment: @Paulw11, okay so using on `DispatchQueue` seems to allow the expiration handler be called, thanks. Should have tried that as that's what I actually have coded for actual stuff. But looks like the counter only reaches 30 seconds now, shouldn't it be allowing a higher amount of time?

Comment: It isn't defined how much time iOS will give you.  iOS does look at the work your app is doing.  Since you aren't performing any network or disk I/O or even using much CPU it suspends your app pretty quickly.